# Executable not searching from PATH variable

Tags: macos, bash, go, grafana

I am trying to build grafana on my MAC. I installed the go binary and updated the PATH variable.Below is the output of bash

`bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/Users/kartl/Projects/mongodb/bin/:/usr/local/go/bin/go:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/kartl/.npm-packages/bin:/Users/kartl/Projects/mongodb/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/kartl/.npm-packages/bin:/Users/kartl/Projects/mongodb/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/kartl/.npm-packages/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin/jamf`

But when I am trying to run some go command for installation, I get below errors.

```
/Users/kartl/Projects/grafana/bin/godep  restore 
godep: restore: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
godep: restore: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
godep: restore: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Can someone help me as why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `/usr/local/go/bin/go` be `/usr/local/go/bin`?
The items in the PATH variable should be directories containing executables, not the executables themselves.

Comment: Thanks a TwilightSun and Daniel. You were right. It should be the directory name and not the executable. This resolved my issue.